# Cache dependency in circleci

Tags: circleci

I'm using CircleCI for our build pipeline and git-secrets for scanning the code base for any aws access keys. Currently for every build, I have to clone git-secrets and install it before building my code. I want to clone this repo into some other folder outside my code repo and cache it across builds. When I'm trying to use the documentation provided in circleci here https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/how-cache-works/ ,it tried to create the folder irrespective of whether it's cached or not, due to which the directory creation fails as it was already created the last time the build ran. The config that I'm using is as under:

```
pre:
    - pip install awsebcli
override:
    - mkdir -p ~/secrets
cache_directories:
    - "~/secrets"
```

secrets is the folder which I have created to clone and install the git-secrets repo.

Comment: My suggestion would be to switch completely to CircleCI 2.0. 1.0 is being EOL'd very soon making finding this solution wasted effort.

Comment: @FelicianoTech Is there any solution for this is version 2.0.

Comment: Yes, follow the CircleCI 2.0 Caching Doc instead: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/